# Dubai transit visa - help with specific scenario

Tags: visas, transit, dubai

I've done some research, called airlines and here are the details:

- Indian national
- YYZ - DXB Air Canada
- DXB - GOI SpiceJet
  Both flights arrive/depart at Terminal 1 DXB (which is good). The problem is that these tickets have been booked separately, which means I'd have to recheck in baggage at DXB.

In order to check in the baggage again, I need a Dubai visa as I'd be entering the country. To do so as an Indian national, I need to apply for a visa in advance (not eligible for on-arrival visa).

Some have suggested baggage transfer services instead of visa but I cannot do so, because Air Canada will not let me board without the visa from YYZ (they will not recognize the second half of my flight with SpiceJet, so for them my final destination is DXB).

So my option is to get a visa, preferably the transit visa. The time between arrival and departure at DXB is 6 hours. Here are my main questions:

1. Does the 8-hour minimum requirement for transit visas apply to **ON-ARRIVAL transit visas only**, or does the same 8-hour requirement apply if I get the **transit visa IN ADVANCE**?
2. If it applies to transit visas in advance as well, how will I be able to exit and get my luggage to check it in again, since I won't be meeting the 8-hour transit visa requirement?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The 8-hour requirement for transit visas only applies if you are departing on the same airline that you arrived on.

As you are arriving and departing on different airlines, you will be able to apply for a transit visa despite having a connection of less than 8 hours.

As an Indian citizen, you will need to apply for a transit visa in advance. The only exception is if you have a US Green Card or US visa, in which case you will also be allowed to obtain one on arrival in Dubai.

Once you have your visa, you can then decide if you want to actually use it, or just rely on the (paid) Marhaba service, which will transfer your bags for you.

Comment: Is there an online/official source for the 8 hour requirement not applying when travelling through different airlines? Just want to be 100% sure, thanks a lot for the explanation Doc!