# Dubai - transit visa or other type of visa?

Tags: visas, transit, dubai

My question is regarding DXB visa.
My trip is as follows, both are SEPARATE TICKETS:
BOM-DXB IndiGo
DXB-YYZ Air Canada
Indian National (not eligible for on-arrival DXB visa)

Can I arrive from BOM to DXB on a Friday, visit Dubai/Abu Dhabi, and take a flight out to YYZ on Sunday? (So about 48 hours in Dubai/Abu Dhabi)?

I would intentionally like to have 2 days in between so as to allow me to visit relatives (will not be staying at a hotel)

1) Does this count as me "transiting", considering it's 2 separate tickets? What type of visa will I need to get in advance?
2) My other option is arrive in DXB 6 hours before my YYZ flight (and not visit my relatives). As they are separate tickets, I will have to recheckin luggage and hence will anyways require a transit visa, correct? (baggage services are not an option for me)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In both your scenarios, you will require a transit visa.

In the first case, as your transit is more than 24 hours, so you don't qualify as a transit passenger. Irrespective of the fact that you have two tickets; the fact that you stay is longer than 24 hour disqualifies you as a transit passenger.

For you second scenario - you normally would not need a visa, however as you are traveling on two separate itineraries you will need to show eligibility to be landed in Dubai before you are allowed to board in India. Your baggage would be checked to Dubai only.

Lets say you are traveling with cabin bags only. You still have the problem that you don't have a boarding pass for your Canadian flight.

Obtaining a 96-hour transit visa is simple; the only real requirement is a hotel reservation; and of course proof of travel. The minimum transit time for eligibility for a transit visa is 6 hours.

You can apply for it once you land in Dubai.

Comment: In the first case, when you say you "you don't qualify as a transit passenger", you mean I don't qualify for TWOV, correct? That is, I can apply for the 96 hour visa and be fine?  
Also, according to this thread, the 8 hour minimum requirement does not apply if I have separate tickets? Hence, I was wondering how it would differ if I have 6 hours to "transit" vs 48 hours.  
 https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111039/dubai-transit-visa-help-with-specific-scenario
Additionally, if my next flight is in 6 hours, how would I be required to have a hotel booking? 
Thank you

Comment: In the first case, you are not a transit passenger at all. Period. However, you do still qualify for the transit _visa_. If you are transiting less than 6 hours, you do not qualify for the transit visa; you have no choice but to stay airside.

Comment: You are confusing the visa requirements vs. your travel status. There are two simple rules: [1] Anyone, who is transiting through Dubai, with a wait time of more than 6 hours, and who holds a valid Dubai hotel reservation, is eligible for a transit visa. [2] The maximum you can stay inside the terminal (air side) in transit is 24 hours. If your transit is more than 24 hours - then you **must** enter Dubai; which means you need to arrange a hotel (or have the airline arrange accommodations for you), and apply for the transit visa.